# Remove Bixby public submission

Tags: bixby

I accidentally created a public submission while developing my capsule.

I do not see a remove or delete feature within the submission form of the Bixby IDE.

How can I delete/remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove public submissions (in fact, you can't remove a private submission either). It is fine to leave the wrong submission there - nothing is done with it unless you submit it for review. Just use a different version number for your next submission.